# Why javascript stop working when reset filterrific or change page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, turbolinks, filterrific

**PROBLEM**

Javascript of my web application built in `Ruby-2.3.3`, `Rails 4.2.7.1` stopped working when I reset filters of `Filterrific 2.1.2` or change page, with pagination provided by `Will_paginate 3.1.5` and `Will_paginate-bootstrap 1.0.1`.

I notice that when `Turbolinks 5.0.1` is disabled, the problem was gone.

**JAVASCRIPT EXAMPLE**

`bootstrap-datepicker-rails 1.6.4.1` stop working after filters are reset. Also any code included in file `application.js`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: "pt-BR",
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

**QUESTION**

Anyone has a solution that's not involve disable Turbolinks? I also tried the gem `jquery-turbolinks` and get no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you initilize your frontend logic in `$(document).ready`, but when using Turbolinks you have to do it in `$(document).on('turbolinks:load')`.

For deeper knowledge take a look at [Building your turbolinks application](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#building-your-turbolinks-application) section of official documentation

Comment: Works great! Since a rails default application came with turbolinks gem, I never read the documentation. And that's about to change. Thanks.

Comment: @fmmatheus feel I have to mention - if you in example will use js libraries like select2 which create additional elements and store their state in jquery-data, which flashes on page change you may notice strange behaviour when using back button. In this case - destroy that components in `turbolinks:unload` event.

Comment: Great advise @aleksandr, I will do that.